# Validation empty fields in MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, validation, mvvm

I have a XAML with about 100 controls. All of them are bound to class Student.

I can validate such pool like Age, or Name, but how to validate controls,which user not even touch ?

For example for field Address.

Address couldn't be null, but user forgot about filling this control.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is something called `ValidationRule` in WPF. You should try googling for this or if you got the Book "WPF Unleashed" look after page 298.

Answer (score 1):

Set [ValidatesOnTargetUpdated](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.validationrule.validatesontargetupdated.aspx) to true on your ValidationRule and it will run when the binding is initialized instead of only when the user modifies the data.

You could also have your Student class implement [IDataErrorInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.idataerrorinfo.aspx) and set [ValidatesOnDataErrors](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.binding.validatesondataerrors.aspx)=True on your Bindings.  This uses [DataErrorValidationRule](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.dataerrorvalidationrule.aspx), which has ValidatesOnTargetUpdated set.

Answer (score 1):

There is a cool library called FluentValidation, http://fluentvalidation.codeplex.com/, it has a bunch of ValidationRules built in and makes it really easy to implement new ones.
This was intended as a comment, but alas I have not enough points...